# C# core WCF SOAP1.2 binding with media type application/xml

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I have a task to POST to HTTP service endpoint which accepts `Content-Type: application/xml` header and body in the form of SOAP envelope. The response `Content-Type` is also always `application/xml` with SOAP envelope contents.

WCF SOAP1.1 message version specifies that `Content-Type` should be `text/xml`; while WCF SOAP1.2 message version specifies that `Content-Type` should be `application/SOAP+xml`.

I don't have control over the service endpoint so I somehow need to make WCF accept `Content-Type: application/xml` response header.

Right now I receive an error:

```
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException : The content type application/xml; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly.
```

Comment: As the error says, the type does not match [content-type application/xml; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the bound content-type (text/xml; charset=utf-8)].

Comment: You can try to use [custom message encoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-message-encoder-custom-text-encoder) or use [IDispatchMessageinsepctor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) and IclientMessageinspector interfaces to modify HTTP request headers and soap envelope

Answer (score 0):

Try using BasicHttpBinding instead of wsHttpBinding